# Optimising the model-view transformation in GLSL for 2D

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

So, the standard way to transform vertices and then pass to the fragment shader in GLSL is something like this:

```
uniform mat4 u_modelview;
attribute vec4 a_position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_modelview * a_position;
}
```

However, I am working in 2D so there is redundancy in the 4x4 matrix. Would it be more efficient for me to do this?

```
uniform mat3 u_modelview;
attribute vec3 a_position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(u_modelview * a_position, 1.0);
}
```

gl_Position requires a 4 component vector so an extra operation is required at output. However the matrix multiplication is for 9 elements instead of 16. Can I do any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that graphics hardware transforms with 3x3 and 4x4 matrices for the same amount of time. Do you have a proven bottleneck at the process of transforming vertices? Usually slowdown appears at the fragment shader, not the vertex

Comment: "I think that graphics hardware transforms with 3x3 and 4x4 matrices for the same amount of time." - do you have any specific reason for thinking this, as the number of operations for 3x3 matrix is obviously smaller? There is no bottleneck yet, but I am writing opengl-es for mobile devices so want to squeeze as much power out of the gpu as possible..

Comment: Yes, I have a specific reason - the hardware architecture. Graphic accelerator's ALUs have shader cores that process any vertex operation for a constant count of clock cycles, thus having a constant time for a 3x3 and 4x4 cases. Also, focusing your optimization effort on something that is not the actual bottleneck won't pay back to you, for example if your bottleneck is taking 30% of frame processing time and you speedup a vertex stage that is taking 0.2% of that time, you're doing a no-op :)

Comment: It's correct that a dot product of 3 or 4 component vectors takes exactly the same time (typically 1 cycle nowadays), but multiplying with a 4x4 matrix still takes 4 dot products instead of 3. Though I agree with you that trying to save this one dot product is kind of a silly optimization because this will make zero difference even on a mobile device. It might in fact even be slower on _some_ hardware (requiring an extra temp register and move for swizzling in the w component - not all hardware can swizzle freely into output registers).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you have complex information per-vertex and it's a bottleneck for you, then if you decrease the per-vertex data you should see some speed increase.

The best thing is to set up a test and measure it both ways.